# Sandbox "Apple ID Password" login alerts forever

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I keep on getting "Apple ID Password" login alerts for two of my App Store test accounts.  They appear some time after reconnecting back to internet; but it seems a bit random.  They also do not appear all the time or immediately, when I run my app.

When I run my app (the only one, so they can't be from other apps), none of my code is getting called.  Neither do I call iOS methods that may cause these alerts to appear.

What can I do to stop getting these alerts?

Comment: having the same issue, did you find solution?

Comment: @ThePoet Having checked my code several times, I concluded that it might be Apple sandbox.  So I kindly requested then (iTunesConnect support if I remember correctly) to remove the affected test user(s), or clear all pending stuff.  Some days later, the sh*t stopped :-)

Comment: I guess I found the reason, I believe you can't delete the test user as I did, if the transaction is not finished on the device, it keeps some sore of cache forever... all the other test accounts I am using work fine and stop displaying this window

Comment: @ThePoet Sound familiar indeed.  I remember deleting test users to no avail.

Comment: @ThePoet So how do I solve it? I need to test In-App purchase reliably, but I have these alerts hounding me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if you make multiple receipt refresh requests using

```
refreshRequest = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] init];
[refreshRequest start];
```

Comment: I wrote "Neither do I call iOS methods". Why do you think this is an answer to that old issue of mine?

Comment: I'm adding in case someone else searches and finds your issue, as I did.